# Windows 8.1 Store quits after load screen even after wsreset

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-8.1, windows-store-app

I just reinstalled my system to a new SSD because my HDD died, but because I have a Win 8 key I went through with the Win 8 (x64) install than the Win 8.1 update from the store. Than I reinstalled and configured every software I use except the metro apps and yesterday I wanted to reinstall those too but the Store simply quits at the load scrn or when the start page is loaded.
So I searched the internet for solutions but it seems none of them worked so far.

I tried to run wsreset.exe (this simply starts the store which obviously crashes after a few second)

Than I tried this:

```
powershell -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register $Env:SystemRoot\WinStore\AppxManifest.XML
```

this didn't help either

Than I run the Store Apps debug tool (AppsDiagnostic.diagcab) which also resets the Store but it still crashes than it showed me a summary which said that the Store cache is damaged and it wasnt repaired and the store configuration is probably damaged

Than I tried this diag tool again but this time after the store reset it said that probably my VGA driver is outdated (which isn't because I installed the latest a day before) than at the end on the summary screen the diag tool showed that Windows probably doesn't recognised hardware changes
So I reinstalled the VGA driver but the result is still the same.

Than I found an MS blog where they writing abut having problems with store on domain network, I'm not connected to a domain network but anyways I checked out the Registry if All Aplication Packages has the right permissions than on Program Files folder the same and there were no problems with permissions.

So now I'm stuck with a non working Store and I don't know what to do next to make it work without preforming a Windows Reset, which I really don't want to do because than I will have to reinstall and configure everything again. *(and last time I tried Win Reset it totally chrashed Windows)*

What can I do to make it work?

Comment: You have UAC enabled right?  This might not be solvable since you have made permission modifications.

Comment: UAC disabled and did not made permission modifications I just checked if the permissions are right or not.

Comment: UAC is required to launch `Windows Store` applications including `Windows Store`.

Comment: Ok sorry not disabled just set to the minimum and any other store app is working properly like: Calendar, Mail, Photos, Contacts, etc.. only the store wont work and as I wrote it starts but after a few sec it quits